# Receive argument Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a small ftp client using apache lib. I am returning list of files in ArrayList

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class myftpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<FTPFile>> {
    public FTPFile[] FTPFile;
    FTPClient mFtp = new FTPClient();

    @Override
    protected List<FTPFile> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<FTPFile> myFiles = new ArrayList<FTPFile>();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            mFtp.connect(params[0], 21);

            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtp.getReplyCode())) {
                mFtp.login(params[1], params[2]);
                mFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFtp.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_html");
                FTPFile files[] = mFtp.listFiles();



                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // does not enter here
                    //Log.d("F-> " , ((FTPFile) files[i]).getName().toString());
                    //myFiles.add((FTPFile) files[i]).getName().toString());
                    myFiles.add(files[i]);
                }
                Log.v("Files", myFiles.toString());
                mFtp.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            try {
                mFtp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return 1;
        return myFiles;

    }
}
```

And I am receiving it like this

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        List<FTPFile> listofFiles;

        listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().execute(
                "*****", "*****", "******");

        ArrayAdapter<FTPFile> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FTPFile>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listofFiles);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }



}
```

But it throwing an exception of cannot cast to list.

Where is the problem?

Regards

Comment: which line are u getting error/

Comment: where I am receiving the array as list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this compile

```
 listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().execute(
                "*****", "*****", "******");
```

???

`newmyftpTask().execute();` returns object from this type  `AsyncTask<String, Void, List<FTPFile>>`

use this instead

```
 listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().execute(
                    "*****", "*****", "******").get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just a little fix :)

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM :**

```
listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().execute(
                "*****", "*****", "******");
```

you are cast wrong way

**SOLUTION 1:**

use  [get ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method for getting result back from AsyncTask in main UI Thread as:

```
 listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().execute(
                    "*****", "*****", "******").get();
```

**NOTE :**

this solution pause your main thread execution until response not come back from AsyncTask as doc says

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

use `onPostExecute(List<FTPFile> result)` for updating Ui without hanging of Ui when AsyncTask execution complete

just change your code as:

```
public class myftpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<FTPFile>> {

   //your code here

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<FTPFile> result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   ArrayAdapter<FTPFile> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FTPFile>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  }

}
```

and start myftpTask task as from main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        new myftpTask().execute("*****", "*****", "******");
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(myftpTask, int, List<String>) is undefined. Error, Implementing your solution.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain : where is this line in your code as you shared in code if you have some latest code then also post it

Comment: @MurtazaHussain : where is  constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(myftpTask, int, List<String>) line your code if you share relevant code then i will try to help u more

Comment: Instead of receving FTPFIle object and sending a string.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(List<String> listofFiles) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPostExecute(listofFiles);
  this.myadapter = new listAdapter(this, R.layout.customlistview,
    listofFiles);
  setListAdapter(this.myadapter);
 }

Comment: @MurtazaHussain  : ok you want to receive an String ArrayList from myftpTask? then just edit new code in your question i will all what's going wrong

Comment: Ok, I will if I need help. Thanks btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

For getting return value from AsyncTask you have to use its [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method,

Replace,

```
listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().
                                         execute("*****", "*****", "******");
```

With,

```
listofFiles = (List<FTPFile>) new myftpTask().
                                    execute("*****", "*****", "******").get();
```

But, this will block your UI Thread. So, better would be to create an `Interface` or `BroadCastReceiver` to return the value/data from AsyncTask. [Here](https://github.com/lalit3686/AsyncTaskReturnValue) is a demo for the same.